# Subscriber not generating output!

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, laserscan, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am making a **simple subscriber which will subscribe to /lms200** topic on which **Laser Data is being published.**

**I went through the ROS tutorial [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), and wrote the following subscriber node, it has been complied successfully but neither it generate any output not any error.**

***Here is my sample code:***

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "redirector");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("lms200", 1000, chatterCallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

following is the output when i executes the **$rospotic echo /lms200**

```
header: 
  seq: 296
  stamp: 
    secs: 1417864716
    nsecs: 451817364
  frame_id: lms200
angle_min: -1.5707000494
angle_max: 1.5707000494
angle_increment: 0.0174000002444
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0
range_min: 0.10000000149
range_max: 20.0
ranges: [9.380000114440918, 9.380000114440918, 9.380000114440918, 9.390000343322754, 9.390000343322754, 9.399999618530273, 9.420000076293945, 9.430000305175781, 9.449999809265137, 9.470000267028809, 9.5, 9.529999732971191, 9.5600004196167, 9.59000015258789, 9.630000114440918, 9.670000076293945, 1.7699999809265137, 1.7699999809265137]
intensities: []
```

**and following is the output when i executes the following command:-**

```
cr-lab-tu@crlabtu-HP-Z800-Workstation:~$ rostopic info /lms200
Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Publishers: 
 * /RosSim (http://crlabtu-HP-Z800-Workstation:55152/)

Subscribers: 
 * /redirector (http://crlabtu-HP-Z800-Workstation:40278/)

cr-lab-tu@crlabtu-HP-Z800-Workstation:~$
```

**Please help me out to solve the problem.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199008/subscriber-not-generating-output!!/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add message type to subscriber and correct message type in call back. check 1,2,3 comments

---

```
//2. recieves message of laserscan type
void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->header.seq); // 3.prints sequence number of scan
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "redirector");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
   //1. add message type sensor_msgs::LaserScan to subbscriber
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("lms200", 1000, chatterCallback); 
   
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-06**:
hello @bvbdort, thanks a lot for looking into it, i have followed your code and also included "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h" file, but it is generating following at comment 3:-

```
const struct sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘seq
```

how can i resolve this, Thank you :)

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-06**:
sorry, i missed that seq is member of header.  i updated it

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-06**:
thank you so much @bvbdort for your kind help, it was giving 1 more warning as:

```
format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 8 has type ‘std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void> >::_seq_type {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
```

I've fixed it by using %d instead of %s in comment 3

thanks

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-06**:
its working now!!!